# Can there be multiple Main methods with different declarations in same class in c#

Tags: c#

We know that the **Main** method is the entry point of a program and we can use multiple Main methods in different classes if we specify the compiler **StartupObject** of the method. What will the scenario if we have **multiple Main method in same class with different declarations** ?  Can we specify the compiler in method level ?

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Test");
        }
        static void Main()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Test 1");
        }
    }
}
```

update: The output was an error CS0017  Program has more than one entry point defined. My main doubt here was can we specify StartupObject at method level or do any other properties exists to do this.?

Thanks

Comment: have you tested it?

Comment: The compiler says: 
`Error CS0017 Program has more than one entry point defined. Compile with /main to specify the type that contains the entry point.`

Comment: Tested with different classes, in same class level it was throwing an error. my question here was can we specify the StartupObject property upto  Method level..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define multiple types with each having a `Main` method, and you can specify which of those types to treat as the entry point with the compilation flag `/main`.

To my knowledge, you can't have two different overloaded `Main` methods in one type and tell the compiler which method to use. If the goal is to have one `Main` that takes input arguments and one that is parameterless, one workaround might be to use the `params` keyword to effectively make the parameter optional.

```cs
class Program 
{
  static void Main(params string[] args)
  {
    if (args.Length > 0)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Test");
    }
    else
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Test 1");
    }
  }
}
```